# How to get number of concrete classes from factory pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, factory-pattern

Factory pattern usually creates a base class for the concrete classes and the concrete classes then inherit from that base class. For a lot of applications, we need to know the number of the concrete classes this factory can create. For instance, a factory that creates the typical Shape objects (circle, rectangular, etc.) C# code example below:

```
public class ShapeFactory
{
    public IShape GetShape(int shapeIndex)
    {
        IShape s = null;
        const int color = 1;
        const int thickness = 5;

        switch (shapeIndex)
        {
        case 1: s = new Square(color, thickness);
            break;
        case 2: s = new Triangle(thickness);
            break;
        case 3: s = new Circle(color);
            break;
        }

        return s;
    }
}
```

The user may want to know how many kinds of shapes are supported by the program. I know 2 ways to do this:

1. Set the number as a constant in the factory class and make it
   visible to public. The drawback is that every time you add a new
   Shape, you have to manually increase the number of shapes.
2. Create a dynamic container (List in C#) that contains all instances
   of the concrete objects the factory can create. The advantage is
   that it can automatically figure out the number of Shapes it can
   create, even if new Shape classes are added. The drawback is
   obvious, every kind of Shapes have to be created together with the
   Shape requested!

What is the best way to do this? Any best practice on this specific topic?

Comment: What is the expected public interface of such factory? Can you show some code?

Comment: Can you give an example of when you would need to know the number of the concrete classes the factory can create?

Comment: @YacoubMassad, please see the edit.

Comment: @adv12, in the example in my question, how to know how many kinds of shapes are supported by the program? For instance, if the program takes command line argument (e.g. shapeIndex) to create a shape object, I'd like to show the user what the maximum shapeIndex can be.

Comment: Guys, if you down voted the question, could you please give a valid reason?!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the types of shapes in an array then use Activator to create the instance. This takes care of indexing, count, and simplifies your creation function.

```
static class ShapeFactory
{
    private static readonly Type[] _shapes = new Type[] { typeof(Square), typeof(Triangle), typeof(Circle) };

    public static int FactorySize
    {
        get
        {
            return _shapes.Length;
        }
    }

    public static IShape GetShape(int shapeIndex, params object[] ctorParams)
    {
        return (IShape)Activator.CreateInstance(_shapes[shapeIndex], ctorParams);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Marco. This is a great solution, but how can you cope with constructors that takes various number of parameters? say, Square's ctor takes (int color), Triangle's ctor takes (int color, int thickness), etc.

Comment: @james see edit. just add a object[] parameter. see the docs for info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx

Comment: thank you for this workaround. I'll accept your answer. However, this solution expose the construction details to the caller (e.g. constructor parameters for different Shapes) which may not be a good design. If you compare your code with the original, you can see that the original code only requires a single parameter, shapeIndex. The other constructor parameters may be **fixed** as constants in the GetShape function. I would appreciate it if you could kindly provide a suggestion for this?

Comment: I think this breaks the intended use of the Factory pattern because it requires the "inherent" understanding of constructor's params (that have to agree in Number, Order, and Type) as the constructor of each concrete impl. class) This is actually bad design

Comment: @james if that's the case, you could go back to your previous switch statement and populate the object[] array with the necessary constants then pass that into the function

Answer (score 2):

You could create an Enum that has the constants stored for you.
This also helps helps users by knowing the 'possibilities' by the IDE's auto complete features, plus it prevents the user from entering a number 'out of bounds' such as entering '4' in your example. (Mind you I generally write java... so C# isn't my forte, but you can do 'something' similar to this)

```
public class ShapeFactory
{
    enum PossibleShapes {CIRCLE, 
                    SQUARE, 
                    TRIANGLE, // c# allows you to do this (extra comma) on constructors, not sure about Enums, and helps with reducing 'bad' line changes in git/etc.
                    };
    public IShape GetShape(PossibleShapes whichShape)
    {
        IShape s = null;

        switch (shapeCode)
        {
        case PossibleShapes.SQUARE : s = new Square(color, thickness);
            break;
        case PossibleShapes.TRIANGLE: s = new Triangle(thickness);
            break;
        case PossibleShapes.CIRCLE: s = new Circle(color);
            break;
        }

        return s;
    }
}
```

The "issue" of having to edit the class each time you add a new possibility is moot, because you WILL have to edit this class each time you do that, now you just have to edit the 'PossibleShapes' class too.

(Mind you, I still don't think this is proper usage of the Factory Pattern, because I have no clue where the 'color' and 'thickness' values are coming from, but at least this is better than using reflection)

Comment: Thanks, @mawalker. but this does not tell the caller **how many** concrete classes can be created, which is the question that I asked in the first place...

Comment: And could you please elaborate a bit on why this is better than using reflection?

Comment: Then just create a static #, because that is all you need to do, or a method that returns that #. However, I don't see -why- you would need to give this information to the end user. The reason this is better is because 1) it hides the constructor details, 2) reflection is expensive 3) There is less code in this pattern than there would be if you added all the params checking logic to make sure the params were valid 4) Probably more that I can't think of off the top of my head, but security and predictability come to mind.

Comment: I updated my answer to use an Enum, This gives a list to the user of the valid possibilities and if they want a count they can get it via `Enum.GetNames(typeof(PossibleShapes)).Length;` or you can make that a helper method of the factory class.

Comment: The only time I could see returning the # of valid options from a factory as a possible good idea is when you have a class, such as BouncyCastle(java) that can support different Algorithms, and it returns to you a list of the algorithms it can provide from the current run time, however, if you want to 'count' that list... just .getSize()/.length from the returned object/size, etc. I still think that you have a larger design flaw with your API if users need to ask how many concrete impl. there are.

Comment: Thanks again for your explanations, @mawalker. one use case is that the user may want to know how many kinds of shapes are supported by the program. For instance, if the program takes command line argument (e.g. shapeIndex) to create a shape object, I'd like to show the user what the maximum shapeIndex can be and I don't want to change this value each time I add a new shape class.

Comment: Even in the CLI example, I just don't think that is a solid argument, because you will need some functionality even in that case to tell the user WHAT options exist, and in that 'output' you would put 1 = Square, 2= Triangle, 3=Circle, 4 = etc. And the 'max count' is inherently in that by the highest # you give them.

Comment: unless you envision a user from the command line just 'randomly' picking to create shape '2', without knowing what that shape is. And if so, then you should have a `GetRandomShape()` method.

Comment: I'll give this answer an up vote for the time and efforts you contributed, and also to show my appreciation. yes, I will have to tell the user what options exist, as you could imagine, by some text output, for example. But the ability to automatically deduce the number of concrete classes is still helpful - say, in error handling, if the user select option 5, which is not exist, i may want to let him know the valid option range are [1, 4], etc. And more importantly, I don't need to change all the code that uses this 'max count'.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) Example that I think does a better example encapsulating your object creation for you. (You could use the Factory Method pattern instead of having different named Methods for each Shape you want to 'get' within the builder)

Plus this allows the user to set the color/thickness themselves easily (can still have defaults, but I didn't put that into this code example)

Represents a product created by the builder

```
public class Shape
{
    public Shape()
    {
    }

    public int Color { get; set; }

    public int Thickness { get; set; }
}
```

The builder abstraction

```
public interface IShapeBuilder
{
    // Adding NotNull attribute to prevent null input argument
    void SetColor([NotNull]string colour);

    // Adding NotNull attribute to prevent null input argument
    void SetThickness([NotNull]int count);

    Shape GetShape();
}
```

Concrete builder implementation

```
public class ShapeBuilder : IShapeBuilder
{
    private Shape _shape; 

    public ShapeBuilder()
    {
    }  

    public int GetNumberShapesPossible() 
    { 
        //return some # here 
    } 

    public void GetSquare(){
        this._shape = new Square();
    }

    public void GetCircle(){
        this._shape = new Circle();
    }

    public void SetColor(string color)
    {
        this._shape.Color = color;
    }

    public void SetThickness(int thickness)
    {
        this._shape.Thickness = thickness;
    }

    public Shape Build()
    {
        return this._shape;
    }
}
```

The director

```
public class ShapeBuildDirector
{
    public Shape Construct()
    {
        ShapeBuilder builder = new ShapeBuilder();

        builder.GetCircle();

        builder.SetColour(2);
        builder.SetThickness(4);

        return builder.GetResult();
    }
}
```

You are going to have to change **some** code somewhere when you want to add new concrete classes to your library. Unless you plan on bundling the concrete classes as some kind of .dll There is just no way around that. There will have to be some edit to a builder/factory/etc somewhere.